# Is there a way to add Types Definition/Declaration for bind functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-declaration, type-definition

I'm learning TypeScript now and I have been wanting to create and contribute my own Type Def File.

So I was having trouble lately to get the Intellisense to work with the type because of this binding function

```
declare module 'jshue' {
    export interface IHue {
        discover: () => Promise<Array<any>>,
        bridge: (ip: string) => any
    }
    var jsHue:IHue = jsHueAPI.bind(null, fetch, Response, JSON, Promise);
    export default jsHue;
}
```

The problem with this is that when I import the library and try to use it, an error message will be prompted saying that

```
This expression is not callable.
Type 'IHue' has no call signatures.
```

It will work if I declare a type when declaring jsHue, It's just that it will defeat the purpose of having type definition file.

```
import jsHue, { IHue } from 'jshue';
const hue:IHue = jsHue();
```

Also, is there a way that I could avoid declaring a new variable with jsHue()?

Is there any other solution for this to work?

[JS Library for jsHue](https://github.com/blargoner/jshue/blob/master/src/jshue.js)

Comment: Uh, you don't want to use `bind`, you want to use `call`? There's no reason to partially apply that function.

Comment: Or if that's just how the libary is written (and you can't change it and just want to provide types), then you should probably use `var jsHue: () => IHue;`

Comment: Hi @Bergi, var jsHue: () => IHue; works! Thank you so much!

Comment: So, there's no way that I can avoid declaring jsHue() in the type def file?

Comment: Not if the library stays written like that.

Comment: I have fork the library to my github, how do I get rid of the declaration and just import jshue and use it directly?

Comment: In that case, do `module.exports = jsHueAPI(fetch, Response, JSON, Promise)` (or just drop the entire IIFE), and `import hue from 'jshue'`. You might even want to switch to ES6/TS `export` syntax, and/or declare the types right inside that module instead of providing a separate declaration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the help from Bergi
Solution here https://github.com/blargoner/jshue/pull/23